# C++: high-level XML serializing library

Tags: c++, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm looking for a *high-level* XML library with an interface similar to `boost::serialization` to automatically serialize C++ objects in XML:

I'm dreaming this scenario (this is the deserialization part):

- You register your C++ types associating them to an XML tag (what `boost::serialization::make_nvp` plus `boost::<Archive>::register_type` do)
- For any type you supply a function to say what children that type needs/accepts and where to store them (similar to what `boost::serialization::serialize` do)

That's it. This should be enough to deserialize XML files in a very simple/high-level way. Is there anything like this?

---

Boost::serialization would be perfect, but it cannot fit the job because of a couple of issues:

- The tag associated to a type is defined within such type `serialize` function. For my purpose the tag should be defined before entering such function (ie: in the parent deserialization function).
- You must know a priori what type you're expecting (what type you're going to read). This is also due to the above issue.

The way `boost::serialization` serializes out (ie: generates) XML should already be compatible to what I'm looking for...

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to serialise? Do you have design control over it? Huge difference between serialising existing data types you can't modify, and designing your system from scratch with serialisation in mind.

Comment: I don't think it actually matters: boost::serialization is able to serialize any kind of data. It needs a `serialize` function which can be both member or non-member (in the latter case, it must be placed in `boost::serialization` namespace).

Comment: Why do you want to use XML? [YUK]. There are open source libraries available for platform independent data serialisation conforming to ASN1.1 [YUK] (check Wikipedia). This is a long established format used heavily for typed data transport across a network link.

Comment: just because you can use a separate global function for existing data definitions doesn't mean you can actually write the serialisation function. Just for example .. what happens if some of the data is in a class and is private? (Which is pretty normal isn't it?)

Comment: @Yttrill: I need to use XML because the XML files already exist, and I need to load the data they contain. In case of issues anything is fine, but I didn't get your point: what private data has to do with what I need? I would need to define a serialization function, it could be member of the class, or friend of the class, whatever is fine...

Comment: Have you considered going a step further and insulating your application from XML altogether by using XML data binding? This way you don't even need to register anything manually. You can, for example, try [CodeSynthesis XSD](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsd/). Or, for a lighter-weight, dependency-free variant, you can try [CodeSynthesis XSD/e](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/xsde/).

Comment: Have you tried http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/?

Comment: TinyXML may help you which was written by C++. http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyxml/